# WordPress: Get taxnomy terms which also uses a second taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Let's say I have a website which sells cars.

I'm using a custom taxonomy called `brand` for the manufacturer (like BMW, Audi, ...) and a custom taxonomy called `type` for the type of cars (like SUV, Coupe, ...).

For the cars itself I'm using a custom post type called `models`.

Now I want to show every car `brand` in the taxonomy archive for `type` (All brands with SUVs).

To do that, I'm trying to get all `brands` and filter them with all `types`.
As result there should be a list with all car brands that have SUVs.

Here's my current code to get a list of brands:

```
$taxonomies = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'brand',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );
 
if ( !empty($taxonomies) ) :
    $output = '<select>';
    foreach( $taxonomies as $category ) {
        if( $category->parent == 0 ) {
            $output.= '<optgroup label="'. esc_attr( $category->name ) .'"></optgroup>';
        }
    }
    $output.='</select>';
    echo $output;
endif;
```

I couldn't find a way to add a second taxonomy to this snippet.
Is this the wrong approach?

Maybe I need to get the custom post types (models) first to check which one has both terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/getting-wordpress-term-results-that-are-relative-to-a-different-taxonomy/) has a really helpful breakdown.

I needed to get the taxonomies that were part of another taxonomy for use in creating a dropdown (and some other uses.)  This code allowed me to identify the "categories" that were part of a particular "destination".

```
$dest_slug = get_query_var('term');
$desination_ids = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'item',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'destinations',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $dest_slug
    )
),
'fields' => 'ids'
));
$categories = wp_get_object_terms($desination_ids, 'category');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works:

```
$productcat_id      = get_queried_object_id();
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => array('models'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $productcat_id,
        ),
    ),
);

$cat_posts  = get_posts($args);

$my_post_ids = wp_list_pluck ($cat_posts, 'ID');
$my_terms    = wp_get_object_terms ($my_post_ids, 'types');

if ( !empty($my_terms)) :
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $my_terms as $my_term ):

            $brand_name = $my_term->name;
            $brand_link = get_term_link($my_term);

            echo '<li><a alt="'.$brand_name.'" href="'.esc_url( $brand_link ).'">'.$brand_name.'</a></li>';

        endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
```